# Laravel/Eloquent escape quote character

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I'm using Laravel for the first time and I'm encountering a SQL syntax error when saving an Eloquent model to the DB.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'. (SQL: update [plan_part] set [plan_id] = 48, [is_astm_testing_complete] = 0, [supplier_part_weight] = .0308, [hazard_class_type_id] = 42, [supplier_additional_details] = test's, [modified_by] = 1003 where [plan_part_id] = 55826)

It has to do with `supplier_additional_details = test's` where I have an apostrophe in the value.

I'm confused as to why this is happening because I thought the Eloquent save method was using PHP's PDO and bound parameters, as evidenced by the stack trace in the error response:

`Connection->runQueryCallback('update [plan_part] set [plan_id] = ?, [is_astm_testing_complete] = ?, [supplier_part_weight] = ?, [hazard_class_type_id] = ?, [supplier_additional_details] = ?, [modified_by] = ? where [plan_part_id] = ?', array('48', 0, '.0308', '42', 'test\'s', 1003, '55826'), object(Closure))`

I can see that the apostrophe appears to have been automatically escaped (I didn't do anything to add the slash), but don't bound parameters automatically do this for me?

Why is Laravel erroring out on this when it appears to have been escaped properly anyway? Am I expected to manually escape every single input in my controller logic?

That seems wrong and unnecessary, but again, I'm not super familiar with Eloquent/Laravel.

The save logic is pretty straightforward:

`$plan_part = PlanPart::find(...);
...
$plan_part->supplier_additional_details = $request->supplier_additional_details;
$plan_part->save();`

What am I doing wrong?

FWIW, I'm using a SQL Server not MySQL, so I'm not sure if there a nuances there that I don't understand.

**UPDATE**
Looks like SQL Server uses double single-quotes instead of slashed single-quotes for escaping. Anyone know what I'm supposed to do to get Laravel to work with SQL Server better?

Comment: Doing some more research, it looks like SQL Server doesn't use the slash as an escape character and instead uses a double single-quote. I'm betting that's the problem as Laravel probably isn't designed to natively handle SQL server.

Comment: you might want to make an issue at [`laravel/framework`](https://github.com/laravel/framework) to raise awareness.

Comment: Look at this file for more details. /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php

Comment: Thanks, I've opened an issue with the GitHub for Laravel (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24123). I'll try to review the Query Builder to see if I can figure out where/how these escape characters are coming into play. They have different "Grammars" for the different SQL drivers, but so far I haven't found out where the quotes (and potentially other chars) are getting escaped at.

Comment: Looks like Laravel is just doing PDO's `bindValue` (\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php). I'm wondering if my SqlSrv driver is not configured properly or what (I've never setup PHP to SQL Server...this is just a project I overtook for work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that our PHP web server was not configured with the appropriate SQLSRV PDO drivers.  We had a goofy setup where we were running PHP on a FreeBSD box but pointing to a SQL Server database.  The FreeBSD box did not have the PDO drivers for SQL Server and Microsoft doesn't provide any for that particular OS without requiring manual compilation, etc.

We ended up migrating our web servers to IIS and were able to rectify the problem by installing the Microsoft-provided SQLSRV PDO drivers for IIS/Windows.